# Django Rest API shows only some urls

Tags: python, django, url-pattern, django-rest-viewsets

I have created a polls app with the Django tutorial and have added a REST API, again with the tutorial.

I think I have an error somewhere in my urlpatterns config because I can see only some pages, the rest give me an error.

My root url.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from polls import views, viewsets

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('polls.urls')),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += [
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

My app-level url.py:

```
from . import views, viewsets
from .viewsets import QuestionViewSet, UserViewSet, ResultsViewSet
from rest_framework import renderers
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'questions', viewsets.QuestionViewSet)
router.register(r'users', viewsets.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'results', viewsets.ResultsViewSet)

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

viewsets.py:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Choice, Question
from .serializers import QuestionSerializer, UserSerializer, ChoiceSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import permissions
from .permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework import viewsets

class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class ResultsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Choice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChoiceSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'questions': reverse('question-list', request=request, format=format),
    })
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Choice, Question

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        #excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='questions', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Question.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.question_text = validated_data.get('question_text', instance.question_text)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='choices', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

URLs that are OK:

http://localhost:8000/

http://localhost:8000/polls/

http://localhost:8000/polls/1/

http://localhost:8000/polls/1/results/

http://localhost:8000/polls/1/vote/

http://localhost:8000/users/            (why does this work as only API related link?!)

http://localhost:8000/api-auth/login/

http://localhost:800/admin/

URLs that are not OK:

http://localhost:8000/questions/

http://localhost:8000/results/

---

Please let me know if you need to see any other code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

when Django show you urls it means you entered incorrect url.
for example when you want to open admin page, you should enter :
`localhost:8000/admin/` in your url 

i think you should use

```
http://localhost:8000/polls/questions/
```

instead `http://localhost:8000/questions/`

Comment: Hello, 
```http://localhost:8000/polls/questions``` doesn't work either. And I'm trying to get the api view, not the questions themselves.
So, that's not the issue...